# Controller redirection doesn't change view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing a simple RedirectAction in my controler and in this new Controller i'm calling the new View, however in the Browser the View is not changing, i can see in the cshtml the code getting there, but i don't know what i'm missing.

```
public ActionResult ExecuteBreakdown(string param1)
{
    return RedirectToAction("ShowMatrix", "BreakdownMatrix", new { param = param1 });
}

public ActionResult ShowMatrix(string param1 )
{
    ...lots of code
    return View("ShowMatrix", priceMatrix);
}
```

I'm not being redirect to the ShowMatrix View.

Comment: Can you show us the origin ActionResult?

Comment: Are you doing any kind of Ajax calls?

Comment: open network tab of F12 tools in your browser and check if you get the expected 302

Comment: No AJAX calls, i will put the action result here but i can see it in the cshtml class, i don't think it's a problem. No error 302 also, it just keeps in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something like a `PartialView`  in your redirect to action call. However, the call needs to be scoped to a parent view that can display the partial properly. You can't just load what you send over like that.

Comment: Hmmm.. how do i do that?

Comment: Based on how you asked your question, I think you are trying to load a partial view within a view but not necessary have the view refresh, hence redirect to action. Is that right?

Comment: I found a pattern that works form me. Declare an Index view that has a PostActionController and a PostAction property. Load the Index view and have a BeginAjaxForm section that loads your partial using the Index.PostActionController and Index.PostAction as route values, a second trip. Here you make a second trip to load your partial, this time using an ajax call, from the ajaxform's context. The secret here is to convert your partial to a string server side and expose it as a property on your model then when loaded simply set a placeholder.html() to your ajaxform's  data.PartialHTMLString.